# On Click and Window Scroll display or hide menu style - jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

```
var nav = $('#topNavBar');
    var navCss = {
      "background-color":"#ffffff",
      "box-shadow" : "0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.26)",
      "-webkit-transition" : "all 0.2s ease-out",
      "-moz-transition" : "all 0.2s ease-out",
      "-ms-transition" : "all 0.2s ease-out",
      "-o-transition" : "all 0.2s ease-out",
      "transition" : "all 0.2s ease-out"
    };


    $('.navbar-toggle').on("click", function() {

      if (
        nav.find("#bs-navbar").is(':hidden') && !nav.hasClass("navbar-solid")) {

          nav.addClass('navbar-solid');
          nav.css(navCss);

      }
    });
  }
```

Full code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rejQrr?editors=0010

The app is build with Bootstrap3.

When window width scale below 768px Bootstrap changes the way the menu is rendered, and you get those drop down menus like in mobile apps.

I made a function to add and remove CSS class and inline style on window.scroll().
When is > 100 px from top adds:
.navbar-solid
and inline CSS style from var navCss

When is < 100 then it removes those.

So far so good.

Now what I need is to be able to click on the button to display the menu, while under 768px when you are able to see it, and toggle the background color and the inline CSS style for transitions.

If the background color is visible, meaning that class .navbar-solid and the var navCss inline then do not apply the stuff. 
If they are not visible, then apply them.

As you can see my results are not really working out well :)
I tried lots of stupid multiple conditions and I realized in the end is not a good approach so I stopped. Best is to ask some one else with another perspective maybe.

What to do?

Thanks,
George